# css rendering on some pages while not on others

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a masterpage on which I have kept some css styles . But when I run the application the css is being added on some pages while not on others and also it is rendering on some elements of the pages and not on other.

here's the code:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="Site2.master.cs" Inherits="abc.Site2" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="stylesheets/StyleSheet1.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
    ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul#pri.nav {
  margin-left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 97%;
  background-color: rgb(180, 221, 180);
}

ul.nav {
  height: 10px;
}

ul.nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 10px 13px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  line-height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
}

ul.nav#pri li {
  margin-top: 0px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT';
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-bottom-color: inherit;
  border-bottom-width: medium;
  background-color: #0fc15e;
}

ul.nav#pri li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

ul.nav#pri li.active,
ul.nav#pri li:hover ul.nav#sec {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT';
  color: #a67cd5;
}

.nav#pri li:hover ul {
  color: #2b95b2;
}

ul.nav#sec {
  display: none;
  /*float:left;
text-align:center;
border-top-right-radius:15px;
border-top-left-radius:15px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;


 font-family:'Arial Rounded MT';
 font-size:15px;
 color:#fff;
 margin-top:-1px;
 width:97%;
    */
  /*height:25px;
 border-top-right-radius:15px;*/
}


/*ul.nav#pri li li.active
{

}*/
      .auto-style2 {
        height: 550px;
      }

      .auto-style3 {
        height: 454px;
        margin-top: 40px;
      }

      .auto-style4 {
        height: 133px;
        margin-top: 81px;
      }

      .auto-style5 {
        margin-left: 57px;
      }

      .auto-style6 {
        width: 123px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body style="height: 600px">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="auto-style2">
      <div class="auto-style2">
        <div class="auto-style3">

          <div style="margin-top :80px">
            <div style="width:100%; float:left; margin-top: -20px;">
              <div style="float:left; width:44%; text-align:justify; margin-left:20px; 
   margin-top:-20px;">

                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Height="40" Width="150" ImageAlign="Middle" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ Logo.png" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />
          <br />

          <div>
            <ul id="pri" class="nav" style="height: 10px; margin-top: 30px">
              <li class="active"><a href="AfterLogin.aspx">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="rubrics.aspx">Rubrics</a></li>
              <li><a href="CreateUser.aspx">Create User</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Reports</a>
                <ul id="sec" class="nav" style="margin-left: 3px">
                  <li><a href="a">a</a></li>
                  <li><a href="b">b</a></li>
                  <li><a href="c">c</a></li>

                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="auto-style6"><a href="AdminMessaging.aspx">Messages</a></li>

              <li class="auto-style5">
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="logout" onclick="logout_Click">Sign Out</asp:LinkButton>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>

          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">





          </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
    <div id="p1" class="auto-style4">
      <div style="height:10px;"></div>

      <div style="color:#F5F5F5;text-align:center;">
        Copyright © xyz
      </div>
    </div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

external stylesheet :

```
           #p1
{
     width:100%;
    background-color:#0a6438;
    height:100px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
    margin-top:-5px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    width :initial;

}
```

I am not getting the requiered css for the footer.

Comment: @Gerardo BLANCO

Comment: Your external styles for `#p1` will be overwritten by the styles for class `auto-style4`.  So if you are expecting a `height: 100px` and `margin-top:  -5px`, but what will actually be applied is `height: 133px` and `margin-top: 81px`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you are not getting your styles rendered when the page is not in the root of the website, but rather in a folder.

Change the link to:

```
<link href="~/stylesheets/StyleSheet1.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
```

To get it to render a relative path appropriate for the location of the actual page being rendered.

I would also recommend not mixing your styles inline and in the stylesheet. Put them all in the external sheet.

Comment: I do have the pages in the root of the website.also made the change you suggested,there has been some changes but still the effects like change on hover is not working

Comment: Then I think you need to add a more specific question.

Comment: @Liamm12..Sorry..This question..tagged you in the wrong question ..That was fixed.